# How to pass Joomla form data via Ajax call to controller function

Tags: javascript, ajax, view, joomla, http-post

In my Joomla 3.3 form I inserted an ajax script to update some form fields dynamically.
...mainpart of the script is

```
formdata = new FormData();
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
timeout: 6000,
url: "index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=component.save",
data: formdata,
......................
........
```

After firing the ajax script, $_POST is completely empty in the controller, and I cannot access important formdata.

Meanwhile I tried several ways, eg

```
formdata = new FormData($(this)[0]); => nothing happens
```

or

```
formdata = new FormData();
formdata = $(this)[0]; => nothing happens
```

or

```
formdata = new FormData();
form = $(this)[0];
formdata.append("jform", form) => this fills up my $_POST, but with value undefined
```

How can I pass my formdata (the jform object) to the controller via Ajax POST method?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use serialize function of jQuery:

```
var formdata = jQuery( "#formid" ).serialize();
```

Here formid is id of form element. Hope this helps..

Comment: still the same problem! $_POST ends up empty :-(

Comment: can you please put your html, script and action code here?

Comment: $document->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery("#btn1").click(function() {
   alert ("Button");
    var formdata = jQuery( "#market_photo-form" ).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 6000,
          url: "index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=component.save",
    data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
    success:function(result) {
     jQuery.each(result.data, function(i, item) {
      ..........
     });

    }
     });
  return false;
  });
  });
');

Comment: and now html part:

    form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent'); ?>"
     method="post" name="market_photos" id="market_photo-form" class="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    
    <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
     <legend><?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT'); ?></legend>
     <ul class="adminformlist">
      <table id="table1">
       <tbody>
.....

Answer (score 0):

I recognized two problems!

1) The form is a subform, displayed in a tab. Therefore not the id of the subform should be assigned in the script. You should assign the id of the main form

2) The ajax parameter "contentType: false" should be eliminated

With this parameter the ajax call will do its job!

ajax script:

```
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#btn1").click(function() {
            alert ("Button");
                var formdata = jQuery( "#main-form" ).serialize();
                jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                timeout: 6000,
                url: "index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=component.save",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                success:function(result) {
                    jQuery.each(result.data, function(i, item) {
                        ..........
                    });

                }
        });
        return false;
        });
    });
');
```

html:

```
form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent'); ?>"
    method="post" name="market_photos" id="subform-form" class="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data">   

<fieldset class="form-horizontal">
    <legend><?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT'); ?></legend>
    <ul class="adminformlist">
        <table id="table1">
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<div class="span5">
    <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
        <legend><?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT'); ?></legend>
        <div class="control-group">

......
....
```

I hope these parts give a better insight!